# Jmeter : One request - two or more responses - how to Regular Expression Extractor?

Tags: web-services, jmeter, response

**Hello.**
I met the following problem.

**What I should do:**

1. I need to make a performance test of services. I don't have documentation. In this case, I record the requested services and responses using Jmeter and the browser. Then I review every one sample and add a regular expression extractor - if it's needed.

**What's the problem?**

1. The problem that I met is when I run the script from Jmeter, some requests have two or more responses. When I use regular expression extractor or response assertion, I noticed that the extractor or assertion is applied only to the last response. So can I apply the regular expression extractor and response assertion to responses that I need?
2. Here are some screenshots for more details:

[This picture shows that we have two responses from one request and you can see details about the first response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7ldF.jpg)

[This picture shows details about the second response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l6lS.jpg)

[This picture shows the response code for the first response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEvpo.jpg)

[Same as the previous picture, but I added a Response Assertion - to check if the assertion works for the first response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKXSY.jpg)

[This picture shows the response code for the second response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLxSX.jpg)

[This picture shows the assertion failure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plJSr.jpg)

**Why has this has happened?**

1. Probably this happened because I hit an URL (endpoint), and this URL forces other requests, that weren't recorded. So... maybe I need to configure the recorder options in another way.

**Whats the questions:**

1. Is there is a way to choose what response I can use with a regular expression extractor? For example, there are two responses and I want to use a regular expression extractor to the first one.
2. Which are the best settings for recording using Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

"Whats the answers":

1. No, you have choice between Main sample and sub-samples, main sample only, sub-samples only or JMeter Variable
2. The ones which are defined in the [Recording Template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/templates/recording.jmx) are most probably the best, at least they're better than anything else I've seen so far. The general approach of "recording" might be a big mistake itself, at least for Web 2.0, I believe there are way better options of replicating browser traffic.

Coming back to your first question and possible solutions: you're basically being [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) that's why you're getting 2 subresults, one with status code `302` and another one with `200`

With normal [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) you can only amend its configuration to take both status codes as successful:

[image]

If you want to test that exactly the first subresult has status code of 302 - you will have to go for [JSR223 Assertion and implement the acceptance criteria in Groovy.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)

Example code:

```
if (prev.getSubResults().first().getResponseCode() != '302') {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Response code mismatch, expected: 302, got: ' + prev.getSubResults().first().getResponseCode())
}
```